# Запятая перед ЧЕМ: "больше(,) чем", "важнее(,) чем"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли в данном предложении запятая перед "чем":
Больше(,) чем семья Петровых, важнее(,) чем моё домашнее задание.

Answer (score 3):

Вероятно, что запятые нужны, но нужно посмотреть на предложение целиком.
Запятые в подобных конструкциях ставятся, если наличествуют два сравнимых понятия.

(НЕ) БОЛЕЕ / БОЛЬШЕ, ЧЕМ, в составе сравнительного оборота

Обороты, присоединяемые союзом «чем», выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми, если в предложении называются или подразумеваются два сравниваемых понятия.

Шут необходим толпе более, чем герой. М. Горький, Жизнь Клима Самгина. Кстати, вы, кажется, пострадали более, чем Билль. А. Грин, Джесси и Моргиана. Есть вещи, которые утомляют человека гораздо более, чем сама работа. Л. Улицкая, Пиковая дама. Милый зверь накуролесил на новом месте еще больше, чем у меня. Д. Мамин-Сибиряк, Мeдведко. Вот Додик мой милый, милый и такой умный, он вырастет еще больше, чем ты. Л. Андреев, Великан. Поэт в России – больше, чем поэт… Е. Евтушенко, Молитва перед поэмой. Разбитое на мелкие осколки знание интересовало людей не более, чем всякая другая работа, в которой не видишь смысла и цели. И. Ефремов, Час быка. …Есть люди… которые смыслят в музыке не больше, чем некоторые животные… М. Булгаков, Театральный роман. …Седины у него не больше, чем у меня. А. Битов, Рассеянный свет.

Однако при отсутствии сравниваемых понятий слова «(не) более / больше чем» образуют с последующими словами неразложимое сочетание (единый член предложения), не требующее постановки знаков препинания. Как правило, в этом случае после слов «(не) более / больше чем» следует количественно-именное сочетание (счетный оборот) или название единицы измерения (час, грамм, километр и т. п.).

Таким образом тайна была сохранена более чем полудюжиною заговорщиков. А. Пушкин, Метель. Водка была горькая, разведенная, по случаю праздника, водой более чем на три четверти. В. Короленко, Сон Макара. Егоров вообще не любил, когда начальник розыскного отдела отлучался более чем на сутки… В. Богомолов, Момент истины. На снимке более чем столетней давности был изображен коллектив только что открывшегося мясного храма. В. Аксенов, Новый сладостный стиль. Деревня была уже не более чем в двухстах шагах… Н. Гумилев, Записки кавалериста. Совершенно больной и даже постаревший поэт не более чем через две минуты входил на веранду Грибоедова. М. Булгаков, Мастер и Маргарита. Это разговор не больше чем на двадцать минут… В. Аксенов, Новый сладостный стиль.

(gramota.ru)